# Force GetKeyNameText to english

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, locale

The Win32 function [`GetKeyNameText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeynametextw) will provide the name of keyboard keys in the current input locale.

From MSDN:

> The key name is translated according to the layout of the currently
> installed keyboard, thus the function may give different results for
> different input locales.

Is it possible to force the input locale for a short amount of time?  Or is there another alternative to `GetKeyNameText` that will always return the name in English?

Comment: Did you find a solution @decasteljau?

Answer (score 3):

***Update***: This answer does not work. It actually modifies the keyboard settings of the user. This appear to be a behavior change between Windows versions.

```
CString csLangId;
csLangId.Format( L"%08X", MAKELANGID( LANG_INVARIANT, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL ) );
HKL hLocale = LoadKeyboardLayout( (LPCTSTR)csLangId, KLF_ACTIVATE );
HKL hPrevious = ActivateKeyboardLayout( hLocale, KLF_SETFORPROCESS );

// Call GetKeyNameText

ActivateKeyboardLayout( hPrevious, KLF_SETFORPROCESS );
UnloadKeyboardLayout( hLocale );
```

Comment: Switching Keyboard layout to English takes very long time. Also switching layout back does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: GetKeyNameText is broken (it returns wrong A-Z key names for non-english keyboard layouts since it uses [MapVirtualKey with MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR that is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72464583/1795050)). I cannot recommend dealing with this method at all. :)

You can use [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#scan-codes) to map scan code to HID Usage codes and HID Usage Names:

| Scan code | HID Usage | HID Usage Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00FF | 0x0007001 | ErrorRollOver |
| 0x001E | 0x0007004 | Keyboard A |
| 0x0030 | 0x0007005 | Keyboard B |
| 0x002E | 0x0007006 | Keyboard C |
| 0x0020 | 0x0007007 | Keyboard D |
| 0x0012 | 0x0007008 | Keyboard E |
| 0x0021 | 0x0007009 | Keyboard F |
| 0x0022 | 0x000700A | Keyboard G |
| 0x0023 | 0x000700B | Keyboard H |
| 0x0017 | 0x000700C | Keyboard I |
| 0x0024 | 0x000700D | Keyboard J |
| 0x0025 | 0x000700E | Keyboard K |
| 0x0026 | 0x000700F | Keyboard L |
| 0x0032 | 0x0007010 | Keyboard M |
| 0x0031 | 0x0007011 | Keyboard N |
| 0x0018 | 0x0007012 | Keyboard O |
| 0x0019 | 0x0007013 | Keyboard P |
| 0x0010 | 0x0007014 | Keyboard Q |
| 0x0013 | 0x0007015 | Keyboard R |
| 0x001F | 0x0007016 | Keyboard S |
| 0x0014 | 0x0007017 | Keyboard T |
| 0x0016 | 0x0007018 | Keyboard U |
| 0x002F | 0x0007019 | Keyboard V |
| 0x0011 | 0x000701A | Keyboard W |
| 0x002D | 0x000701B | Keyboard X |
| 0x0015 | 0x000701C | Keyboard Y |
| 0x002C | 0x000701D | Keyboard Z |
| 0x0002 | 0x000701E | Keyboard 1 and Bang |
| 0x0003 | 0x000701F | Keyboard 2 and At |
| 0x0004 | 0x0007020 | Keyboard 3 And Hash |
| 0x0005 | 0x0007021 | Keyboard 4 and Dollar |
| 0x0006 | 0x0007022 | Keyboard 5 and Percent |
| 0x0007 | 0x0007023 | Keyboard 6 and Caret |
| 0x0008 | 0x0007024 | Keyboard 7 and Ampersand |
| 0x0009 | 0x0007025 | Keyboard 8 and Star |
| 0x000A | 0x0007026 | Keyboard 9 and Left Bracket |
| 0x000B | 0x0007027 | Keyboard 0 and Right Bracket |
| 0x001C | 0x0007028 | Keyboard Return Enter |
| 0x0001 | 0x0007029 | Keyboard Escape |
| 0x000E | 0x000702A | Keyboard Delete |
| 0x000F | 0x000702B | Keyboard Tab |
| 0x0039 | 0x000702C | Keyboard Spacebar |
| 0x000C | 0x000702D | Keyboard Dash and Underscore |
| 0x000D | 0x000702E | Keyboard Equals and Plus |
| 0x001A | 0x000702F | Keyboard Left Brace |
| 0x001B | 0x0007030 | Keyboard Right Brace |
| 0x002B | 0x0007031 | Keyboard Pipe and Slash |
| 0x002B | 0x0007032 | Keyboard Non-US |
| 0x0027 | 0x0007033 | Keyboard SemiColon and Colon |
| 0x0028 | 0x0007034 | Keyboard Left Apos and Double |
| 0x0029 | 0x0007035 | Keyboard Grave Accent and Tilde |
| 0x0033 | 0x0007036 | Keyboard Comma |
| 0x0034 | 0x0007037 | Keyboard Period |
| 0x0035 | 0x0007038 | Keyboard QuestionMark |
| 0x003A | 0x0007039 | Keyboard Caps Lock |
| 0x003B | 0x000703A | Keyboard F1 |
| 0x003C | 0x000703B | Keyboard F2 |
| 0x003D | 0x000703C | Keyboard F3 |
| 0x003E | 0x000703D | Keyboard F4 |
| 0x003F | 0x000703E | Keyboard F5 |
| 0x0040 | 0x000703F | Keyboard F6 |
| 0x0041 | 0x0007040 | Keyboard F7 |
| 0x0042 | 0x0007041 | Keyboard F8 |
| 0x0043 | 0x0007042 | Keyboard F9 |
| 0x0044 | 0x0007043 | Keyboard F10 |
| 0x0057 | 0x0007044 | Keyboard F11 |
| 0x0058 | 0x0007045 | Keyboard F12 |
| 0xE037 0x54 | 0x0007046 | Keyboard PrintScreen |
| 0x0046 | 0x0007047 | Keyboard Scroll Lock |
| 0xE11D45 0xE046 0x45 | 0x0007048 | Keyboard Pause |
| 0xE052 | 0x0007049 | Keyboard Insert |
| 0xE047 | 0x000704A | Keyboard Home |
| 0xE049 | 0x000704B | Keyboard PageUp |
| 0xE053 | 0x000704C | Keyboard Delete Forward |
| 0xE04F | 0x000704D | Keyboard End |
| 0xE051 | 0x000704E | Keyboard PageDown |
| 0xE04D | 0x000704F | Keyboard RightArrow |
| 0xE04B | 0x0007050 | Keyboard LeftArrow |
| 0xE050 | 0x0007051 | Keyboard DownArrow |
| 0xE048 | 0x0007052 | Keyboard UpArrow |
| 0x0045 0xE045 | 0x0007053 | Keypad Num Lock and Clear |
| 0xE035 | 0x0007054 | Keypad Forward Slash |
| 0x0037 | 0x0007055 | Keypad Star |
| 0x004A | 0x0007056 | Keypad Dash |
| 0x004E | 0x0007057 | Keypad Plus |
| 0xE01C | 0x0007058 | Keypad ENTER |
| 0x004F | 0x0007059 | Keypad 1 and End |
| 0x0050 | 0x000705A | Keypad 2 and Down Arrow |
| 0x0051 | 0x000705B | Keypad 3 and PageDn |
| 0x004B | 0x000705C | Keypad 4 and Left Arrow |
| 0x004C | 0x000705D | Keypad 5 |
| 0x004D | 0x000705E | Keypad 6 and Right Arrow |
| 0x0047 | 0x000705F | Keypad 7 and Home |
| 0x0048 | 0x0007060 | Keypad 8 and Up Arrow |
| 0x0049 | 0x0007061 | Keypad 9 and PageUp |
| 0x0052 | 0x0007062 | Keypad 0 and Insert |
| 0x0053 | 0x0007063 | Keypad Period |
| 0x0056 | 0x0007064 | Keyboard Non-US Slash Bar |
| 0xE05D | 0x0007065 | Keyboard Application |
| 0xE05E | 0x0007066 | Keyboard Power |
| 0x0059 | 0x0007067 | Keypad Equals |
| 0x0064 | 0x0007068 | Keyboard F13 |
| 0x0065 | 0x0007069 | Keyboard F14 |
| 0x0066 | 0x000706A | Keyboard F15 |
| 0x0067 | 0x000706B | Keyboard F16 |
| 0x0068 | 0x000706C | Keyboard F17 |
| 0x0069 | 0x000706D | Keyboard F18 |
| 0x006A | 0x000706E | Keyboard F19 |
| 0x006B | 0x000706F | Keyboard F20 |
| 0x006C | 0x0007070 | Keyboard F21 |
| 0x006D | 0x0007071 | Keyboard F22 |
| 0x006E | 0x0007072 | Keyboard F23 |
| 0x0076 | 0x0007073 | Keyboard F24 |
| 0x007E | 0x0007085 | Keypad Comma |
| 0x0073 | 0x0007087 | Keyboard International1 |
| 0x0070 | 0x0007088 | Keyboard International2 |
| 0x007D | 0x0007089 | Keyboard International3 |
| 0x0079 | 0x000708A | Keyboard International4 |
| 0x007B | 0x000708B | Keyboard International5 |
| 0x005C | 0x000708C | Keyboard International6 |
| 0x0072 | 0x0007090 | Keyboard LANG1 |
| 0x0071 | 0x0007091 | Keyboard LANG2 |
| 0x0078 | 0x0007092 | Keyboard LANG3 |
| 0x0077 | 0x0007093 | Keyboard LANG4 |
| 0x0076 | 0x0007094 | Keyboard LANG5 |
| 0x001D | 0x00070E0 | Keyboard LeftControl |
| 0x002A | 0x00070E1 | Keyboard LeftShift |
| 0x0038 | 0x00070E2 | Keyboard LeftAlt |
| 0xE05B | 0x00070E3 | Keyboard Left GUI |
| 0xE01D | 0x00070E4 | Keyboard RightControl |
| 0x0036 | 0x00070E5 | Keyboard RightShift |
| 0xE038 | 0x00070E6 | Keyboard RightAlt |
| 0xE05C | 0x00070E7 | Keyboard Right GUI |

**OR** if you're really-really want to get this info from keyboard layout - then you can load and parse it manually from layout dll file (kbdus.dll, kbdger.dll etc).

There is a bunch of undocumented stuff involved:

- In order to get proper keyboard layout dll file name first you need to get `KLID` string (keyboard layout id, see [here for the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts)). US English is `00000409`. If you have `HKL` (from `GetKeyboardLayout` or `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`) then you can convert it to `KLID` string with such code:

```cpp
// Returns KLID string of size KL_NAMELENGTH
// Same as GetKeyboardLayoutName but for any HKL
// https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values
BOOL GetKLIDFromHKL(HKL hkl, _Out_writes_(KL_NAMELENGTH) LPWSTR pwszKLID)
{
    bool succeded = false;

    if ((HIWORD(hkl) & 0xf000) == 0xf000) // deviceId contains layoutId
    {
        WORD layoutId = HIWORD(hkl) & 0x0fff;

        HKEY key;
        CHECK_EQ(::RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Keyboard Layouts", &key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

        DWORD index = 0;
        while (::RegEnumKeyW(key, index, pwszKLID, KL_NAMELENGTH) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            WCHAR layoutIdBuffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
            DWORD layoutIdBufferSize = sizeof(layoutIdBuffer);
            if (::RegGetValueW(key, pwszKLID, L"Layout Id", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutIdBuffer, &layoutIdBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (layoutId == std::stoul(layoutIdBuffer, nullptr, 16))
                {
                    succeded = true;
                    DBGPRINT("Found KLID 0x%ls by layoutId=0x%04x", pwszKLID, layoutId);
                    break;
                }
            }
            ++index;
        }
        CHECK_EQ(::RegCloseKey(key), ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        WORD langId = LOWORD(hkl);

        // deviceId overrides langId if set
        if (HIWORD(hkl) != 0)
            langId = HIWORD(hkl);

        std::swprintf(pwszKLID, KL_NAMELENGTH, L"%08X", langId);
        succeded = true;

        DBGPRINT("Found KLID 0x%ls by langId=0x%04x", pwszKLID, langId);
    }

    return succeded;
}
```

- Then with `KLID` string you need to go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\%KLID%` registry path and read `Layout File` string from it.
- Load this dll file from `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_System, ...)` (usually `C:\Windows\System32`) with `LoadLibrary()` call.
- Next you need to do `GetProcAddress(KbdDllHandle, "KbdLayerDescriptor")` - you're receive pointer that can be casted to `PKBDTABLES`.
- There is `kbd.h` header in Windows SDK that have `KBDTABLES` struct definition (there is some stuff involved to use proper KBD_LONG_POINTER size for x32 code running on x64 Windows. See my link to Gtk source at the end).
- You have to look at `pKeyNames` and `pKeyNamesExt` in it to get `scan code` -> `key name` mapping.

**Long story short**: The GTK toolkit have the code that doing all this(see [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/main/gdk/win32/gdkkeys-win32-impl.c) and [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/main/gdk/win32/gdkkeys-win32.c)). Actually they are building scan code -> printed chars tables from Windows keyboard layout dlls.