# MapVirtualKey returns wrong chars in MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR mode

Tags: windows, winapi, input, keyboard

I trying to use `MapVirtualKey[A]/[W]/[ExA]/[ExW]` API to map `VK_*` code to character by means of its `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR (2)` mode.

I have found that it always returns `'A'..'Z'` chars for `'VK_A'..'VK_Z'` no matter which keyboard layout I have active.

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyw) are saying that:

> The uCode parameter is a virtual-key code and is translated into an
> unshifted character value in the low order word of the return value.
> Dead keys (diacritics) are indicated by setting the top bit of the
> return value. If there is no translation, the function returns 0.

But I cannot get `unshifted character value` nor non-ASCII character from it.

For other buttons it works as described. And this behavior is even more annoying considering that, for example for US English keyboard layout it returns:

```
VK_Q (0x51) -> `Q` (U+0051 Latin Capital Letter Q)
VK_OEM_PERIOD (0xbe) -> `.` (U+002E Full Stop)
```

But for Russian keyboard layout it returns:

```
VK_Q (0x51) -> `Q` (U+0051 Latin Capital Letter Q)
                ^- here it should return `й` (U+0439 Cyrillic Small Letter Short I) according to docs
VK_OEM_PERIOD (0xbe) -> `ю` (U+044E Cyrillic Small Letter Yu)
```

How to use it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MapVirtualKey` has a [known broken behaviour](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/03/25/1948887.html).

**UPDATE JAN 2023:** Microsoft [docs was updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/pull/1376) to include this behavior.

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyw) are lying you about `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR` or `2` mode.

According to experiments and [leaked Windows XP source code](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/working-windows-xp-source-code-posted-to-4chan-update) (in `\windows\core\ntuser\kernel\xlate.c` file) it contains different behaviour for 'A'..'Z' VKs (those VKs are specifically not defined in Win32 API `WinUser.h` header and are equivalent to 'A'..'Z' ASCII chars):

```cpp
    case 2:

        /*
         * Bogus Win3.1 functionality: despite SDK documenation, return uppercase for
         * VK_A through VK_Z
         */
        if ((wCode >= (WORD)'A') && (wCode <= (WORD)'Z')) {
            return wCode;
        }
```

Not sure why MS decided to pull this bug from Win 3.1 but current situation on my Windows 10 is like this.

Also [some keyboard layouts](https://kbdlayout.info/features/ligatures) can emit multiple WCHAR characters on a single key press ([UTF-16 surrogate pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters) or [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)#Ligatures_in_Unicode_(Latin_alphabets)) that can contain multiple Unicode code points). `MapVirtualKey` with `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR` is will return `U+F002` value (defined as `WCH_LGTR` in `kbd.h`) in this case.

As a workaround I can recommend you to use [ToUnicode[Ex]](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex) API that can do this mapping for you:

```cpp
// Returns UTF-8 string
std::string GetStrFromKeyPress(uint16_t scanCode, bool isShift)
{
    static BYTE keyboardState[256];
    memset(keyboardState, 0, 256);

    if (isShift)
    {
        keyboardState[VK_SHIFT] |= 0x80;
    }

    wchar_t chars[5] = { 0 };
    const UINT vkCode = ::MapVirtualKeyW(scanCode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX);
    // This call can produce multiple UTF-16 code points
    // in case of ligatures or non-BMP Unicode chars that have hi and low surrogate
    // See examples: https://kbdlayout.info/features/ligatures
    int code = ::ToUnicode(vkCode, scanCode, keyboardState, chars, 4, 0);

    if (code < 0)
    {
        // Dead key
        if (chars[0] == 0 || std::iswcntrl(chars[0])) {
            return {};
        }

        code = -code;
    }

    // Clear keyboard state
    {
        memset(keyboardState, 0, 256);

        const UINT clearVkCode = VK_DECIMAL;
        const UINT clearScanCode = ::MapVirtualKeyW(clearVkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
        wchar_t tmpChars[5] = { 0 };
        do {} while (::ToUnicode(clearVkCode, clearScanCode, keyboardState, tmpChars, 4, 0) < 0);
    }

    // Do not return control characters
    if (code <= 0 || (code == 1 && std::iswcntrl(chars[0]))) {
        return {};
    }

    return utf8::narrow(chars, code);
}
```

Or even better: if you have Win32 message loop - just use `TranslateMessage()` (that calls `ToUnicode()` under the hood) and then process `WM_CHAR` message.

PS: Same applies to `GetKeyNameText` API since it calls the `MapVirtualKey(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR)` under the hood for keys that do not have explicit name set in keyboard layout dll (usually only non-characters do have names).

Comment: Hi DJm00n, do you know if this behavior changed sometime in 2022? I'm pretty sure that it worked as you expected previously.

Comment: @sfider MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR produces 'A'..'Z' for 'A'..'Z' virtual keys regardless of keyboard layout - this behavior hasn't changed in decades. It just wasn't explicitly documented. I have already made edits to the documentation on the microsoft site. Show me an example when it worked differently, if you can, please - I have not seen this before...

Comment: When I was developing the Keyboard Layout-Independent Input plugin for Unreal Engine, between 2019-2020, I think I was getting some other characters for Russian keyboard. But, to be honest, I probably remember this wrong.

Comment: Just a reminder: `U+F002` is `WCH_LGTR`, so — in a certain limited sense — this is “a correct output”.